# Measuring amperage with multimeter restarts RPI zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, multimeter, gpio, amperage

I wanted to measure amperage on the GPIO pins on my RPI zero, so I attached my multimeter with positive lead to the 3.3V GPIO BOARD 1 and the black ground lead to the GRD GPIO BOARD 39.

My multimeter read about 1.4 amperes ,but I noticed the "on" indicator light on the RPI flickered and turned off.  I checked my Pi and it had restarted.

From my knowledge of using a multimeter, this seemed like an okay thing to do but the Pi reacted adversely.  Does anyone know what I did wrong or what's going on?

Comment: The ammeter is a low resistance. You are shorting the power supply and forcing it to 0V. You need to place the multimeter in series with the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **NEVER** measure current by connecting the ammeter across a power source! An ammeter is close to a short circuit and you shorted out the power to the RPI!

To measure current, you place the ammeter **in series** between the power source and the power consumer. So if you want to see how much current the RPI is drawing, you need to place the meter between your power supply positive terminal and the RPI's positive input pin, replacing the wire that was there.

Comment: I did some research on what a short actually is and from my understanding a short is bad because an unwanted circuit is created and a massive amount of current can do bad things. But shouldn't the GND be able to handle such a spike?  I understand we have fuses and circuit breakers so I'm likely wrong to think this.

Comment: So if I have a load and resistors, then the forward voltage near the negative terminal is close to 0.  Do I have that right?

Comment: @engineer-x The problem is you are erroneously creating a new path for current to flow that completely bypasses the intended circuit with a very low resistance, so now, instead of the power supply just powering the intended circuit, it's trying to power your new short circuit, and it cannot generate that much power (or if it could, your meter would break, fuses would pop, or wires could melt), so it just fails. It has nothing to do with "spikes" or what the purpose of a ground node is. This is also a good way to pop the fuse in your multimeter

Answer (score 3):

They are not GPIO pins. What you tried to measure are the 3.3 power supply and ground pins, on a pin header connector.

And you tried to measure current when short circuiting the supply pin to ground with multimeter, which obviously the Raspberry Pi power supply can't handle, and supply voltage was momentarily zero by the short circuit and chips do reset if you bring the supply voltage zero with a short circuit.

Answer (score 3):

An ammeter has a low resistance connection between the probes.  Given that you were measuring 1.4 amperes, the internal resistance of the meter was probably less than 1 ohm.

That was the same as it you had connected a piece of wire from the 3.3V supply (pin 1) to ground (pin 39.)  You short circuited the power supply.

Ammeters are normally connected in series rather across.

You are lucky that you didn't damage the power supply.

Comment: Well, depending on the power supply. Some of them can deal with short circuits quite gracefully. And if the wiring resistance was high enough, maybe it wasn't even overloaded! The Pi is recommended to be used with a power supply that can supply 2.5 amps, so 1.4 is no problem for it. But yes, **sometimes** this can damage the power supply.